# Replacing text in .ai, .pdf, .eps etc for print in Python

Tags: python, pdf, vector-graphics, adobe-illustrator

My problem boils down to this: I have an Adobe Illustrator file with a simple pattern to be etched into an object using a laser. Each object has an ID tag that until now has been manually edited before each print to the laser. We are wanting to do this programmatically, so I am trying to write a script that can find the tag as text in the file, replace it, then save it.

The file type is flexible so long as it is vector-based, and so is the language. I'm just most familiar with Python. So far I haven't been able to find a module that can simply open a .pdf, replace some text, then save it. The closest I have gotten is manually editing the text in a pdf using sublime text. Is my approach to this problem wrong, and if so are there any better solutions? Thank you.

Comment: can you post a link to this type of file?

Comment: You will be much better off researching what scripting Adobe Illustrator itself can do for you. Editing PDFs is extremely hard, and fraught with problems.

Comment: @usr2564301 That may be the way to go, I'll look into it if this doesn't work out. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally this is a bit difficult, because PDF files have information about where to place strings of text. If you wanted to add a sentence you would have to manually move the rest of the text to the right places in order for it to work. However, if you only want to change a word, and as you say it can be done by changing the text in an editor, you can use a simple substitution.

I grabbed a small bit of a sample PDF to illustrate:

```
import re

s = '''BT 
/F1 0010 Tf 
69.2500 628.8480 Td 
( And more text. And more text. And more text. And more text. And more ) Tj 
ET 
BT 
/F1 0010 Tf 
69.2500 616.8960 Td 
( text. And more text. Boring, zzzzz. And more text. And more text. And ) Tj 
ET 
BT 
'''

changed_s = re.sub('text', 'NOT-TEXT', s)
```

After this snippet `changed_s` will have all occurences of "text" replaced with "NOT-TEXT".

To apply this to a file you can do something like this:

```
import re

# Read from file
# Even better: SVG or illustrator file
with open('filename.pdf', 'r') as f:
    file_text = f.read()

# Perform substitution
changed_text = re.sub('to-change', 'change-to', file_text)

# Write to file
with open('outfile.pdf', 'w') as f:
    f.write(changed_text)
```

You can read up on [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) if you need to do a more involved find and replace.

Comment: That's how far I got actually, but the main problem I've had is the character encoding of the pdf. I just set the encoding to 'latin1' and it seems to work now. Do you know of any way to change the text justification to align center? This would allow me to have a variable ID length

Comment: There is no 'text justification' in a PDF file, each piece of text is individually placed. In order to achieve any klind of justification you need to know the 'width' of the text when rendered, then position the start of the text so that the remaining text is positioned where you want it.